# Change resultset structure elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

is it possible to change the resultset structure when retrieving data from elastic search?

the problem ist, the timeseries data are sometimes from 3000-8000 records which are a json array with json objects in it ... parsing it in this case not really efficient or necessary so i thought - could a resultset be transformed to just lets say a simple json object with an array of time and array of values? nothing more? 
i could do this in java or php but since we want to have an efficent way of dealing with large datasets we are currently evaluating our options.

Answer (score 1):

You can control what elasticsearch returns using source filtering:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html

It can let you pick which part of the indexed document it will return, which, depending on your index structure could be an array of times and values, or at least, very easily mapped to it using the language of your choice.

Comment: i'm not sure if i can create somethin like this {"time":["2017-12-12 11:11:00","2017-12-12 11:11:01"],"value":["0.245","0.314"]} which would be s simple json without metadata, _source etc.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you can get rid of all the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) to control the results. If you map the result in this way, you should be able to get the hits object to be a JSON array of key: value.

Comment: i read a lot around this topic but i really didn't find a solution for this issue. is it really that unusual to fetch 5000 records from ES and process it within a reasonable amout of time?

Comment: Well, it's definitely not the primary purpose behind elasticsearch, which is a full text search engine..

Comment: good point! what would you suggest in such a case? mysql, postgre etc. are not really fast enough or suitable for such a task ...

Comment: thanks for your comment, this brought me to some alternatives like these https://blog.netsil.com/a-comparison-of-time-series-databases-and-netsils-use-of-druid-db805d471206#.s0360or8b ... guess ES is an option but maybe we reconsider the choice in this special area of application. thanks again!